# Unable to open import and export wizard

Tags: sql-server, import, sql-server-2012, export, ssms

I recently installed SQL Server 2012 on my PC but when I try to open import and export wizard to populate data to my tables it gives below message.

[image]

I have installed SSDT as well.
Kindly let me know how to avoid this.

Thanks
Ar

Comment: What exact version of SQL 2012? Run `SELECT @@VERSION` and post the results.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.2100.60 (X64) 
 Feb 10 2012 19:39:15 
 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
 Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.2 <X64> (Build 9200: )

Comment: As per [this](http://www.mssqlgirl.com/vs2012-ultimate-ssis-start-up-error.html), you could try installing SP1 and CU5 and see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks  3N1GM4 that worked :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [this](http://www.mssqlgirl.com/vs2012-ultimate-ssis-start-up-error.html), you could try installing SP1 and CU5 and see if that helps.